# MongoDB : Memory issue need advise

Tags: mongodb, out-of-memory

I have aggregation pipeline in MongoDB. I try to run this pipeline with small number of document like 200K documents, it's seem to ok.

Then I try it with bigger sample ( longer timestamp period in $match) and I found that there is an error said

```
‘$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes’, ‘code’: 146, ‘codeName’: ‘ExceededMemoryLimit’
```

So I google and see that $push is limited memory to 100 MB. Then I increased memory by using this command

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryMaxPushBytes:2048576000});
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes:2048576000});
```

Then run the same query then it gave me longer running time then different error message like

```
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 67108865 bytes, past the 64MB limit.", 
    "code" : 13548.0, 
    "codeName" : "Location13548"
}
```

It's not always and permanent error, in same period of timestamp as this

```
            "$match": {
                "$and": 
                    [
                        { "TID": /XP/ },
                        { "timestamp": { "$gte": "2021-05-15 00:00:00" } },
                        { "timestamp": { "$lte": "2021-05-25 23:59:59" } },
                        { "Col": /^\d.*$/  },
                        { "MT0": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "Row": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "TRM": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "WRLFTR_0": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "WRLFTR_1": /^\d.*$/ }
                    ]
            }
```

which 43,000,000 documents from $match stage I can get result from this code with no error message.

But In some period of timestamp

```
            "$match": {
                "$and": 
                    [
                        { "TID": /XP/ },
                        { "timestamp": { "$gte": "2021-05-27 00:00:00" } },
                        { "timestamp": { "$lte": "2021-05-27 23:59:59" } },
                        { "Col": /^\d.*$/  },
                        { "MT0": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "Row": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "TRM": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "WRLFTR_0": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "WRLFTR_1": /^\d.*$/ }
                    ]
            }
```

which 7,000,000 documents from $match stage I got this error "BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 67108865 bytes, past the 64MB limit."

Here is the code, it's everything I just change parameter name from actual to something else.

```
    db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
                "$and": 
                    [
                        { "TID": /XP/ },
                        { "timestamp": { "$gte": "2021-05-15 00:00:00" } },
                        { "timestamp": { "$lte": "2021-05-25 23:59:59" } },
                        { "Col": /^\d.*$/  },
                        { "MT0": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "Row": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "TRM": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "WRLFTR_0": /^\d.*$/ },
                        { "WRLFTR_1": /^\d.*$/ }
                    ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "TID": "$TID",
                    "Opt": "$Opt",
                    "DSN1": "$DSN1",
                    "DSN2": "$DSN2",
                    "Col": "$Col",
                    "Row": "$Row",
                    "CSN": "$CSN",
                    "PID": {
                        "$switch": {
                            "branches": [
                                { 
                                    "case": { "$eq": [ "$Opt","S5" ] }, "then": "6350"
                                },
                                {
                                    "case": { "$eq": [ "$Opt","FUNC" ] }, "then": "6400"
                                },
                                {
                                    "case": { "$eq": [ "$Opt","STR" ] }, "then": "6600"
                                },
                                {
                                    "case": { "$eq": [ "$Opt","FIN" ] }, "then": "6800"
                                },
                                { 
                                    "case": { "$eq": [ "$Opt", "FTG" ] }, "then": "9000"
                                }
                            ],
                            "default": "$_id.Opt"
                        }
                    }, 
                    "CID": {
                      "$switch": {
                          "branches": [
                          {
                              "case":   { "$and": 
                                            [   
                                                { "$gte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 1.0 ] },
                                                { "$lte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 12.0 ] }
                                            ]
                                        },
                              "then": 1.0
                          },
                          {
                              "case":   { "$and": 
                                            [   
                                                { "$gte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 13.0 ] },
                                                { "$lte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 24.0 ] }
                                            ]
                                        },
                              "then": 2.0
                          },
                          {
                              "case":   { "$and": 
                                            [   
                                                { "$gte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 25.0 ] },
                                                { "$lte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 36.0 ] }
                                            ]
                                        },
                              "then": 3.0
                          },
                          {
                              "case":   { "$and": 
                                            [   
                                                { "$gte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 37.0 ] },
                                                { "$lte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 48.0 ] }
                                            ]
                                        },
                              "then": 4.0
                          },
                          {
                              "case":   { "$and": 
                                            [   
                                                { "$gte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 49.0 ] },
                                                { "$lte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 60.0 ] }
                                            ]
                                        },
                              "then": 5.0
                          },    
                          {
                              "case":   { "$and": 
                                            [   
                                                { "$gte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 61.0 ] },
                                                { "$lte": [ {"$toDecimal": "$Col"}, 72.0 ] }
                                            ]
                                        },
                              "then": 6.0
                          },                          
                      ],
                      "default": 0.0
                  }
              },                                    
                },
                "details": {
                    "$push": {                           // partition over
                        "MT0": "$MT0",
                        "WRLFTR_0": "$WRLFTR_0",
                        "WRLFTR_1": "$WRLFTR_1",
                        "TRM": "$TRM",
                        "timestamp": "$timestamp"
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "_id": 1.0,
                "timestamp": 1.0                        // order by timestamp
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$details",
                "includeArrayIndex": "array_idx"        // row_number
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {                                // select only order 30 - 180 in array
                "$and": [
                    {
                        "array_idx": {
                            "$gte": 30.0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "array_idx": {
                            "$lte": 180.0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {                                // sort TRM for percentile calculation
                "details.TRM": 1.0
            }
        },        
        {
            "$group": {                                // group parameter back to array by partition "_id" 
                "_id": "$_id",
                "timestamp": { "$push": {"$toDate":"$details.timestamp"} },
                "MT0": { "$push": {"$toDouble":"$details.MT0"} },
                "TRM": { "$push": {"$toDouble":"$details.TRM"} },
                "WRLFTR_0": { "$push": {"$toDouble":"$details.WRLFTR_0"} },
                "WRLFTR_1": { "$push": {"$toDouble":"$details.WRLFTR_1"} },
            }
        },          
        {                                               // reporting "_id" and calculating 
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "TID": "$_id.TID",
                "Col": {
                    "$toDecimal": "$_id.Col"
                },
                "Row": {
                    "$toDecimal": "$_id.Row"
                },
                "CSN": {
                    "$substr": [
                        "$_id.CSN",
                        2.0,
                        -6.0
                    ]
                },
                "Opt": "$_id.Opt",
                "PID": "$_id.PID",                 
                "DSN1": "$_id.DSN1",
                "DSN2": "$_id.DSN2",
                "CID": "$_id.CID",                
                "MAX_TRM": {
                    "$max": "$TRM"
                },
                "Q3_TRM": { 
                    "$arrayElemAt": [ "$TRM", {"$floor": { "$multiply": [0.75,{"$size": "$TRM"}] }} ]  
                },
                "AVG_TRM": {
                    "$avg": "$TRM"
                },
                "MAX_WRLFTR_0": {
                    "$max": "$WRLFTR_0"
                },
                "MAX_WRLFTR_1": {
                    "$max": "$WRLFTR_1"
                },
                "MAX_MT0": {
                    "$max": "$MT0"
                },
                "MAX_timestamp": {
                    "$max": "$timestamp"
                },
                "DAY_ID":{"$concat":
                                [
                                    {"$substr":[{"$toString":{"$max": "$timestamp"}}, 0, 4]}, 
                                    {"$substr":[{"$toString":{"$max": "$timestamp"}}, 5, 2]},
                                    {"$substr":[{"$toString":{"$max": "$timestamp"}},8,2]} 
                                ]
                        },
            }
        },
    ],
    {
        "allowDiskUse": true
    }
);
```

**Additional** :
Example of original document :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60934f0aaa31cda568956999"), 
    "TID" : "MX17", 
    "component" : "ABC-DEF", 
    "unique_key" : "XP05ZAVF_20210405_063305_FEAT_none_A0000001_none_A0000002_660835-20210405063327", 
    "timestamp" : "2021-04-05 06:33:27", 
    "CSN" : "0x660835", 
    "Col" : "14", 
    "DefaultMHT" : "40", 
    "DefaultNRR" : "2", 
    "DefaultPRR" : "6", 
    "DF_MRPM" : "2787", 
    "DSN1" : "A0000001", 
    "DSN2" : "A0000002", 
    "EF_MRPM" : "2517", 
    "FT0" : "-1", 
    "FT1" : "-1", 
    "FFT0" : "-1", 
    "FFT1" : "-1", 
    "FMT0" : "-1", 
    "FMT1" : "-1", 
    "FMT0" : "-1", 
    "FMT1" : "-1", 
    "IAVOk" : "1", 
    "ICOnTemp" : "0", 
    "IDFanSpeedOk" : "1", 
    "IHO" : "1", 
    "IOTO" : "1", 
    "IS0PI" : "1", 
    "IS1PI" : "1", 
    "MT0" : "-1", 
    "MT1" : "-1", 
    "MT" : "15", 
    "Operation" : "FEAT", 
    "Row" : "12", 
    "SHTemp" : "35", 
    "SOn1" : "FEAT", 
    "SOn2" : "FEAT", 
    "TATT" : "-1", 
    "TATT" : "-1", 
    "TCCC" : "34.8", 
    "TContMode" : "Ramp To Temperature", 
    "TRef" : "25", 
    "TRAux" : "29.9", 
    "TRMain" : "32.1", 
    "WRFT_Active_now" : "-1", 
    "WRLFTR_0" : "-1", 
    "WRLFTR_1" : "-1", 
    "WRLRATTC" : "-1", 
    "WRLRTFTA" : "-1", 
    "WR_GNRR" : "-1", 
    "WR_GPRR" : "-1", 
    "WR_IOPWCBFT" : "-1", 
    "WR_SIOWCBFT" : "-1", 
    "WOT" : "-1"
}
```

***Example of output :***

```
{ 
    "TID" : "MX17", 
    "Col" : NumberDecimal("70"), 
    "Row" : NumberDecimal("16"), 
    "CSN" : "107D81", 
    "Opt" : "FEAT", 
    "PID" : "9000", 
    "DSN1" : "A0000001", 
    "DSN2" : "A0000002", 
    "CID" : 6.0, 
    "MAX_TRM" : 29.1, 
    "Q3_TRM" : 25.5, 
    "AVG_TRM" : 25.26026490066225, 
    "MAX_WRLFTR_0" : 38.0, 
    "MAX_WRLFTR_1" : 0.0, 
    "MAX_MT0" : 67.0, 
    "MAX_timestamp" : ISODate("2021-04-05T04:48:58.000+0000"), 
    "DAY_ID" : "20210405"
}
```

Comment: Review explain output for clues.

Comment: Example of output :

{ 
    "TID" : "MX17", 
    "Col" : NumberDecimal("70"), 
    "Row" : NumberDecimal("16"), 
    "CSN" : "107D81", 
    "Opt" : "FEAT", 
    "PID" : "9000", 
    "DSN1" : "A0000001", 
    "DSN2" : "A0000002", 
    "CID" : 6.0, 
    "MAX_TRM" : 29.1, 
    "Q3_TRM" : 25.5, 
    "AVG_TRM" : 25.26026490066225, 
    "MAX_WRLFTR_0" : 38.0, 
    "MAX_WRLFTR_1" : 0.0, 
    "MAX_MT0" : 67.0, 
    "MAX_timestamp" : ISODate("2021-04-05T04:48:58.000+0000"), 
    "DAY_ID" : "20210405"
}

Comment: @D.SM edited to have example of input and output for clue.

Comment: Explain output.

Comment: @D.SM expected output is grouping of data with member as     
"TID",  "Col", "Row", "CSN", "Opt", "PID", "DSN1", "DSN2", "CID"
with their summarized info such as max of TRM, AVG of TRM, Q3 of TRM, MAX of WRLFTR_0, max of WRLFTR_1, max of MT0 and max of timestamp in each group.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/